# magento custom link and insertion of form data

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

I have added a link named "campaigns" to the Magento "My Account" area after the Address book. The link, when clicked, should have a form with 4 fields:

```
name
email
number
place
```

Once they submit the form, it should insert these fields in the table. But again, can I want to have custom table for this. I have added this link in the xml file of `/fronend/base/default/layout/sales.xml` like this:

```
<action method="addLink" translate="label" module="sales"><name>orders</name><path>sales/order/history/</path><label>My Orders</label></action>`
<action method="addLink" translate="label" module="sales"><name>campaign</name><path>sales/order/history/</path><label>Missing orders</label></action>
```

Now I'm confused as to which controller and model I have to call, etc.

Please point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

To create a new entity (Campaign, for instance) and allow users to manipulate them, you'll need to define some classes for that new entity. [This tutorial](http://alanstorm.com/magento_advanced_orm_entity_attribute_value_part_1) can help you create new EAV models in Magento.

Once you've done that, you'll need a controller (to run actions that will display your form, save entities, show all the entities, etc). Try [this tutorial](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/25138/) as a starting point.

You'll need to change your path (and it seems your label is off) for your link to accommodate your new controller and show users content as you've specified.

Let me know if you have more questions.

Hope that helps!

Thanks,
Joe